# Import bootstrap 5 component into create-react-app

Tags: javascript, reactjs, bootstrap-5

**Hi** and thanks for the help, I'm using bootstrap 5 to style an app in react, but I'm having trouble including the bootstrap component js. Here I share the code of how I do the import.

```
import "bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.css";
import { Dropdown } from "bootstrap";

function App() {

  return (
      <div>
          <div className="dropdown">
            <a 
                className="btn btn-secondary dropdown-toggle" 
                href="#/" 
                role="button" 
                id="dropdownMenuLink" 
                data-bs-toggle="dropdown" 
                aria-expanded="false">
                   Dropdown link
           </a>

          <ul className="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="dropdownMenuLink">
             <li><a className="dropdown-item" href="#/">Action</a></li>
             <li><a className="dropdown-item" href="#/">Another action</a></li>
             <li><a className="dropdown-item" href="#/">Something else here</a></li>
         </ul>
       </div>
    </div>
  );
}

export default App;
```

When executing the code with `npm start` the app works fine and I have no problem with the bootstrap component the Dropdown displays. The problem is that in the console I receive a warning is the following:

> WARNING in src\component\Sidebar.jsx Line 5:10: 'Dropdown' is defined but never used no-unused-vars

> webpack 5.65.0 compiled with 1 warning in 696 ms

I understand that I have to define Dropdown somewhere, but I don't know where and how. I appreciate the help in advance. The solution to this question is a way to eliminate abstinence using good practice. Well, a simple solution is adding: `// eslint-disable-next-line and esLint` would not show it, but this is not a definitive solution.

- Using react bootstrap is not a solution

**Update**

https://codesandbox.io/s/loving-platform-q6sqy?file=/src/App.js
example in codesandbox

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I have managed to import the js of the bootstrap 5 component, with no errors. Here the code

```
import "bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.css";
import "bootstrap/js/dist/dropdown.js";

function App() {
  return (
    <div>
      <div className="dropdown">
        <a
          className="btn btn-secondary dropdown-toggle"
          href="/"
          role="button"
          id="dropdownMenuLink"
          data-bs-toggle="dropdown"
          aria-expanded="false"
        >
          Dropdown link
        </a>

        <ul className="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="dropdownMenuLink">
          <li>
            <a className="dropdown-item" href="/">
              Action
            </a>
          </li>
          <li>
            <a className="dropdown-item" href="/">
              Another action
            </a>
          </li>
          <li>
            <a className="dropdown-item" href="/">
              Something else here
            </a>
          </li>
        </ul>
      </div>
    </div>
  );
}

export default App;
```

Comment: Some bootstrap components need both CSS and javascript bootstrap. So by installing bootstrapcss and bootstrapjs and importing them both this problem must be solved. This might be better than imporitng the js for each component individually. I replaced your second import with 'import "bootstrap/dist/js/bootstrap.js";' after installing bootstrapjs and it worked fine.

Comment: What you comment about importing all the bootstrap js works. But there is a problem, I will be importing the js of the other components. I don't need the js of the carousel and other components, I only need that of a component. By importing the js of a single component I avoid generating code without using it in the application. And this improves performance, because the application in production will only download only the js that I need and not unnecessary js like the other components that I will not use.

Answer (score 0):

Importing {Dropdown} means you are going to use it as a tag like this: `<Dropdown>`. If you want to use the dropdown class just like you are doing I guess just importing bootstrap would be enough. So you don't need the second import line.

Edit: bootstrap dropdown requires both css and js bootstrap. So remove the second import with `import "bootstrap/dist/js/bootstrap.js"`

Comment: I am not using react-bootstrap. please check the codeanbox  https://codesandbox.io/s/loving-platform-q6sqy?file=/src/App.js

Comment: On the codesanbox, you will notice that the dropdown works and the esLint warning appears on the console. Now do this experiment. Comment on the import dropdown line, the error disappears but the dropdown stops working. Therefore I must always use the import if I want the dropdown to work.

Answer (score 0):

This is correct, you should remove the second import as you import Dropdown class from the bootstrap library, not a React component, so this second import will not work. If you would like to use it as a React component, you need to install react-bootstrap.

Since you are using only bootstrap classes you are good to go, this first import is a correct way of importing bootstrap CSS into the project.